# Restoring Chrome Session

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium

I was using Chrome, and having a lot of tabs open across multiple windows, it just crashed on me.
I opened Chrome again, because I wanted to restore the state. As I was waiting for it to load, I tried to close another program that was running. However Chrome opened on top of it, and I ended up immediately closing Chrome back down

Now when I open Chrome, there is no option to immediately restore the last session. Trying to reopen the last tab doesn't work either. I ran Recuva and manged to get a "Last Session" file, but I do not have the "Last Tabs" file. Is there anything I can do with the Last Session file that can help restore my tabs? Do I have any other options in general?
I had sync on, would all my windows be synced somewhere? I can't look in history, they're not there because the tabs themselves wouldn't actually load when opening the browser, only the active tabs would, so they're not in my history.

Please, I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Google Chrome definitions -> History -> Recent Closed. If you had a lot of tabs opened you should have something like this ***(not my image)*** [image: Example]

If that doesn't solve it then:
Download **Session Buddy** **extension from Google Chrome**.

With this extension you are able to restore a backup from old sessions. I used it only once, but it worked for me.