# How to restore chrome tabs after a reboot if you accidentally closed the restore popup?

Tags: google-chrome, reboot, restore, tabs, session-restore

I had dozen of important tabs I carried for couple days, though I did open and close several other tabs, and then i hat to reboot my computer because it was stuck.

As usual when i launched chrome, there was this popup for me to restore all tabs that were opened at the time of reboot.

[image]

Sadly I accidentally closed. This is not the first time it happens to me so i was searching for another way to get my tabs back. Ctrl+Shit+T or history wont help, because these tabs are not the last opened tabs, as I mentioned earlier, I opened and closed other tabs whiles the ones I kept were still around so they were very "old" and would be scattered through browser history of days.

The only way I could get it back was with the restore button from that popup, but what to do when you accidentally close it ? i'm pretty sure there has to be a way, since its there in chrome's memory, just gotta find out how.

Please help!!!

Comment: History contains many links, not only the last opened ones. Use Ctrl-H to open.

Comment: @harrymc recovering tabs that are weeks old from the history is no solutions, I use my browser very much i'll waste too much time going through the history, and i dont even remember every tab that was opened.

Comment: In my past experiences, and the reason I now use an extension to avoid losing the data, is once you DO NOT restore the tabs Chrome immediately deletes the files required to restore your session.  **You will have to reopen the tabs manually from your history.** If you don't remember which tabs you had open then you are out of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound if what you said is true, then this is heartbreaking.  But some people have had success doing it using an extension, unfortunately it didnt work for me with that extension... https://superuser.com/questions/1572840/restoring-chrome-session

Comment: `History -> Recent Closed` does not actually restore your previous session.  That is one of the reasons that answer has never receive a single upvote (it's inaccurate).  An extension that handles your session, is a solution for the next time you are unable to restore your previous session, it's not a solution for restoring the session you already lost.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, but after that he said: "If that doesn't solve it then: Download Session Buddy extension from Google Chrome."  which really surprised me, because I thought the extension would work only if you had installed it before hand, but he is proposing it as solution for that particular problem, anyways i tried with no success

Comment: The author never suggested the extension would restore closed Chrome sessions.  The extension itself keeps tracks of it's own session data.

Comment: Try Settings>On Startup>Tick-Continue where you left off.  This should  prevent you from losing them next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore Chrome without "Restore" button and the files "Last Session" and "Last Tabs"?](https://superuser.com/questions/342437/how-to-restore-chrome-without-restore-button-and-the-files-last-session-and)